# Store Sessions Timer

Tags: expresso-store, add-on-development

We're looking for a plug in that is already made or someone who would know how to create a plug in for Store that would essentially create sessions for buyers.  What I mean is that someone places Item A in there cart and there is 3 Item As in stock.  Once that Item is placed in the cart it comes out of stock on the system and the person has 10 minutes to buy the product.  At the end of 10 minutes the item is put back in stock if it is not purchased, if it is purchased it is not put back in stock at all.  This would be the same system as say Ticketmaster when you buy tickets.  It holds your tickets for you in a session.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything that exists like this now. I think you'd have to build your own, which, I'm guessing, could be a bit of a complicated process.